# Laravel Project on Ubuntu: Issue redirecting www url to non www url

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, nginx

I have a Laravel 9 project that is hosted on AWS EC2 Ubuntu (ngnix). The domain is registered with GoDaddy and I changed the A record to point it to the IP at AWS EC2. My website runs fine when I used url like example.ca, however, it does not work when I use url **[www.example.ca](http://www.example.ca)** ( I get the default **Welcome to nginx!** page)

As per Google Search I added the following rewrite rule in public/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.ca/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, it did not help. I still continue to get the default Nginx page.

[image]

Is there anything else I need to do? For instance, in **sites-enabled**. I want to add that when I did setup my project, I created a new file in the **/etc/nginx/sites-available** folder with the following contents

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.ca;
    root /var/www/vhosts/example.ca/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing  **server_name example.ca;** to **server_name example.ca www.example.ca;** fixed the issue. (Thanks to Andrew St-Denis.)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.ca www.example.ca;
```